# Spring Data Rest / HATEOAS First and Last Rels

Tags: spring, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

Is there away to enable First and Last paging links in Hal format? Besides creating a Custom `PagedResourcesAssembler` that is?
Seems it like something rather common that could be enabled with a simple setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's currently not supported. Please file an issue in our [bug tracker](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS) and add a link to this question as reference so that we can update the answer once this has been implemented.